# Why does my hair get stuck to my cathode-ray TV screen after it is switched off?

Tags: everyday-life

My dad's old TV! When I switch it off after watching and get my hands closer, my hands' hair gets attached to the screen. And they stick for sometimes! Now, I know how a cathode ray oscilloscope works. It is just the clever use of **Hall - Effect** . But why does my hair get stuck to the screen? What is the cause? Note, I checked this for my LED TV but it didn't work (I couldn't perceive anything) unknowingly. What's the magic in my old TV??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static electricity. The cathode ray tube shoots electrons at the back of the TV screen, which becomes negatively charged. To compensate, and try and maintain electrical neutrality, the front of the screen becomes positively charged (the glass acts as a capacitor).

As you walk across a nylon carpet, its electrons rub off onto your skin, and the hairs on your arm tend to become negatively charged.

The negatively charged hairs on your arm are attracted by the positively charged (electron deficient) screen.

Comment: Note that the hairs don't need to be charged to stick to the screen. The electric field near the screen will polarise the hairs and the resulting electric dipole is attracted to the screen. This effect is why a comb can pick up uncharged pieces of paper in the notorious school experiment.

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: Does this explain why the phenomenon occurs *after* switching the TV off?

Comment: Good question, and no. I would guess that while the TV is in operation, the negatively charged back of the screen, is nearly completely neutralised by the positively charged front of the screen.

When the TV is turned off, the negative side is discharged, leaving the positively charged front of the screen.

Comment: @iantresman: Thanks for the answer and also for the last comment:)